How to Create an LWC Component to Show a Warning When the Industry Picklist Value Changes on a Salesforce Standard Account Page?
I'm working on a custom Lightning Web Component (LWC) to be added to the standard Salesforce Account page. This component aims to display a warning message as a toast notification whenever the Industry picklist value changes.
Trigger Timing: LWC component trigger the toast message immediately after the record is saved.
The above is what I really want to do and here is what I have done:
Create LWC:
HTML (industryChangeNotification.html):
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div if:true={industryChanged}>
            <lightning-toast title="Industry Changed" message="Looks like the industry value is changed just FYI to you." variant="warning">
            </lightning-toast>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

JavaScript (industryChangeNotification.js):
    import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class IndustryChangeToast extends LightningElement {
    @track industryChanged = false;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.subscribeToNotifications();
    }

    subscribeToNotifications() {
        // Example: Subscribe to a custom event fired from Apex trigger
        // Replace with your specific implementation to receive notifications
        document.addEventListener('industryChanged', this.handleIndustryChange.bind(this));
    }

    handleIndustryChange(event) {
        this.industryChanged = true;
        this.showToast();
    }

    showToast() {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Industry Changed',
            message: 'Looks like the industry value is changed just FYI to you.',
            variant: 'warning',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}

Meta XML (industryChangeNotification.js-meta.xml):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <masterLabel>IndustryChangeChannel</masterLabel>
    <description>Channel for Industry Change Notifications</description>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <lightningMessageFields> 
        <fieldName>AccountId__c</fieldName> 
        <description>This is the record Id that changed</description> 
    </lightningMessageFields>

    <lightningMessageFields> 
        <fieldName>OldIndustry__c</fieldName> 
        <description>This is the record Id that changed</description> 
    </lightningMessageFields>

    <lightningMessageFields> 
        <fieldName>NewIndustry__c</fieldName> 
        <description>This is the record Id that changed</description> 
    </lightningMessageFields>
</LightningMessageChannel>

Apex Trigger (AccountTrigger.trigger):
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after update) {
    for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {
        Account oldAcc = Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id);
        if (oldAcc.Industry != acc.Industry) {
            IndustryChangeEvent__e event = new IndustryChangeEvent__e(
                AccountId__c = acc.Id,
                OldIndustry__c = oldAcc.Industry,
                NewIndustry__c = acc.Industry
            );
            EventBus.publish(event);
        }
    }
}

Create a Platform Event:
Name: IndustryChangeEvent__e
Fields:
AccountId__c (Text)
OldIndustry__c (Text)
NewIndustry__c (Text)

I see that it's creating the Platform Events but it's not showing toast message on the Account Record Page

|DEBUG|Platform event published:
IndustryChangeEvent__e:{AccountId__c=00141000008MS0PAAW,
OldIndustry__c=Communications, NewIndustry__c=Biotechnology,
EventUuid=e5e37632-2d67-4518-be18-3991d1227942}

EDIT:
public class IndustryChangeHandler {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void notifyChange(Id accountId, String oldIndustry, String newIndustry) {
        // Optionally, you can perform additional logic here
        // Example: Fire a custom event to notify the Lightning Web Component
        fireEvent(accountId, oldIndustry, newIndustry);
    }

    private static void fireEvent(Id accountId, String oldIndustry, String newIndustry) {
        // Example: Fire a custom event
        // Replace with your specific implementation to fire a custom event
        IndustryChangeEvent__e event = new IndustryChangeEvent__e(
            AccountId__c = accountId,
            OldIndustry__c = oldIndustry,
            NewIndustry__c = newIndustry
        );
        EventBus.publish(event);
    }
}


Where are you listening to the Platform Event? I think you have misunderstood Lightning messaging channel and platfom event listener in LWC. But before going with Platform Events, please have a look at limitations, creating a listener on client page for platform events will have some real issues while scaling as each user who logs in will subscribe to Platform Events, and subscription limit is something which you should consider.

added the class IndustryChangeHandler but can you tell me what other options? if not platform events?

I think Change Data Capture can be suitable for this use case. Related question on SO. Related article

@Nick as Rohit mentioned, you don't need to create a custom event for your use case. Simply enable the Change Data Capture for the Account object and listen to the changes in your LWC component.

@Rohit your suggestion works can you post this as an answer?

@Nick : Happy to know that it is working. Posting the answer in some time.

This use case can be addressed by Change Data Capture (CDC)
First, we need to enable CDC for Account object from below setting:
Setup-> Integrations -> Change Data Capture.

After Saving , filter the CDC to receive changes only for Industry field using PlatformEventChannelMember
Now , we need to subscribe to CDC using LWC component as below :
1.Meta File
<LightningComponentBundle
  xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
  fqn="scores"
>
  <apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <masterLabel>Industry Change Notifier</masterLabel>
  <description>Notifies about account industry change</description>
  <targets>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
  </targets>
  <targetConfigs>
    <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
        <objects>
            <object>Account</object>
        </objects>
    </targetConfig>
  </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>

2.HTML file
<lightning-card>
    <div if:true={industryChanged}>
        <lightning-toast title="Industry Changed" message="Looks like the industry value is changed just FYI to you." variant="warning">
        </lightning-toast>
    </div>
</lightning-card>

3.JS file
import { api, LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue, getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { subscribe, unsubscribe, onError } from 'lightning/empApi';
import INDUSTRY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Industry';

export default class IndustryChangeNotifier extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;

  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId',[INDUSTRY_FIELD]}) account;

  @track industryChanged = false;

  channelName = '/data/AccountChangeEvent';
  subscription = {};

  connectedCallback() {
    this.registerErrorListener();
    this.registerSubscribe();
  }

  disconnectedCallback() {
    unsubscribe(this.subscription, () => console.log('Unsubscribed to change events.'));
  }

  registerErrorListener() {
    onError(error => {
      console.error('Salesforce error', JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }

  registerSubscribe() {
    const changeEventCallback = changeEvent => {
      this.processChangeEvent(changeEvent);
    };

    subscribe(this.channelName, -1, changeEventCallback).then(subscription => {
      this.subscription = subscription;
    });
  }

  processChangeEvent(changeEvent) {
    try {
      const recordIds = changeEvent.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.recordIds; 
      if (recordIds.includes(this.recordId)) {
        this.industryChanged = true;
      } else {
        this.industryChanged = false;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

}

More Info:

Developer Guide
CDC Allocations
CDC Trailhead

